# Enable MySQL autocomplete popup in SQL Developer

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper, mysql-connector

I've recently added MySQL connector to my SQL Developer.
Now I can connect to MySQL no problem, but I noticed that the autocomplete popup is not working, unlike when I use PL/SQL, so I checked the `Tools > Preferences > Code Editor > Completion Insight` and there is no option for enabling the popup for MySQL.
[image]

So I would like to know if anyone knows a workaround for this.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but our IDE only has editor features such as insight/completion implemented for Oracle Database.

While you can use SQL Developer to connect to MySQL, that is only so you can migrate said MySQL instance over to a Oracle Database.

*Disclaimer: I work for Oracle and am a product manager for SQL Developer.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. SQL Developer is a great IDE. So is there any chance that this feature will be added in the future?